# Silence output subprocess.popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

First of all, excuse me for my mistakes, i'm not english.
I'm working on Python3 code.
I want to stop the output of subprocess.popen.

```
def get_interface_ip(interface):
    devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig', interface], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    ip_lan_value = re.findall('192.168.([0-9]*).[0-9]* ', str(output))[0]
    return (ip_lan_value)

def get_lan_ip():
iplan = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
if iplan.startswith("127."):
    interfaces = [
        "eth0",
        "eth1",
        "eth2",
        "wlan0",
        "wlan1",
        "wifi0",
        "ath0",
        "ath1",
        "ppp0",
        ]
    for interface in interfaces:
        try:
            iplan = get_interface_ip(interface)
            break
        except IOError:
            pass
        except IndexError:
            pass
return iplan
```

but it prints:

> eth1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   eth2: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   eth1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   eth2: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato

That means: "Interface not found" (I have active only eth0 and wlan0)

I've tried to use stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb') but it print:

> eth1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   eth2: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   wlan1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   wifi0: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   ath0: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   ath1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   ppp0: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   eth1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   eth2: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   wlan1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   wifi0: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   ath0: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   ath1: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato
>   ppp0: errore nel recuperare le informazioni dell'interfaccia: Dispositivo non trovato

and the program doesen't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are probably printed on stderr. To silence it, use `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered occasions when piping stdout/stderr did not work, in that case you could try need to use a hack, e.g. letting the shell handle the output (example for Linux only, Windows may work similarly):

```
subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig', interface, '2>/dev/null'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: it is unnecessary and wrong. (1) think how a list argument + `shell=True` works on POSIX systems. Compare it with a string argument (that specifies the shell command) + `shell=True` (2) `shell=True` is unnecessary. `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` always works where `2>/dev/null` may work.